# Sort a ManyToMany relation by a column of a joined table

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, doctrine

Is it possible to order a ManyToMany relation by a column of a joined table in an entity with annotations?

I‘ve already tried to get it work with `@ORM\JoinTable` and `@ORM\JoinColumn` but this doesn‘t seem to work.

```php
class Product {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $categories;
}
```

```php
class Category {
    use Knp\Translatable;
}
```

```php
class CategoryTranslation {
    use Knp\Translation;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;
}
```

I would like to do something like `@OrderBy({"CategoryTranslation.name" = "ASC")` in the Product entity. Or is there a way to execute a repository method in the `@ManyToMany` annotation to manually build a query to select the categories with the right order?

Comment: I would say the only  way to achieve this (in db) is to use DQL. The `CategoryTranslation.name` would "magically" require the translation to always be joined (which, ironically, it probably is). *However* the default association apparently is called `translations`, so you could try `translations.name` and see if it sticks. however, one-to-many is notoriously clunky when it comes to sub-fields, so I bet it won't work.

Comment: @Jakumi I did some tests and sadly, as you mentioned, neither of the two methods were working. I would still prefere to sort the categories with annotations (SQL) rather than doing an additional loop with PHP in the getter. Do you know if there is a way to execute a repository method to fetch the categories? Or maybe i could write a custom annotation to extend the Doctrine `@OrderBy` annotation.

Comment: I would probably try this: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/doctrine-relations/collection-criteria inside `Product::getCategories` and hoping `translations.name` works there. However, be aware, that this is only sensible when working with only one product, otherwise you risk getting the n+1 problem. But essentially, with the n+1 problem, you just have to use the criteria elsewhere (in a special repository function for products).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure you can do it through annotations, but I've achieved the result you are looking for with a simple `uasort` function.  In your `Product` entity try something like the following for your `getCategories()` getter.

```
public function getCategories()
{
    $categories = $this->categories;

    uasort($catetories, [$this, 'mySortCategories']);

    return $categories;
}

private function mySortCategories(Category $cat1, Category $cat2)
{
    if ($cat1->getName() === $cat2->getName()) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($cat1->getName() < $cat2->getName()) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: Although i would prefere a way to solve this problems with annotations this is currently the only solution i found and worked for me. Thanks @ehymel. For future reference and people who have the same problem i posted an answer myself to show how i solved it finally.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it the way @ehymel described in his answer but i am using the uasort method of the ArrayIterator object. Im not very happy with this solution because an additional `$locale` parameter is used in the getter method and i would prefere to order the items with SQL/DQL but not an additional PHP loop. But for the moment it works.

```php
public function getCategories(?string $locale = null)
{
    $iterator = $this->categories->getIterator();
    $iterator->uasort(function (Category $a, Category $b) use ($locale) {
        return ($a->translate($locale)->getName() < $b->translate($locale)->getName()) ? -1 : 1;
    });

    return new ArrayCollection(iterator_to_array($iterator));
}
```